# Heroku postgres massive data loss

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I have a postgres Heroku database and accidentally deleted tens of thousands of records.  Is there any built in safeties for this without having a backup?

Comment: Have you checked this out? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-rollback#creating-a-rollback-database

Comment: yeah, will be useful going forward.  Thanks